# Automatic introduce the last part of a time field

Tags: javascript, time, symfony-1.4

How can I automatically introduce, in a time field, the last two digits from time. What i mean is I write `16:` in the field and it automatically puts the last `00`. Something in javascript?
thank you

Comment: When the user leaves the field or when they are typing?

Answer (score 0):

1. listen to the `keyup` or `keypress` event,
2. test if it's a `:`,
3. test if the two characters before the `:` are valid
4. add `00`

Comment: what is `keyup` or `keypress`? events from symfony?

Comment: You don't need any symfony to fix this problem, it's all on the client's side, if I understand you correctly. If you're using jQuery, you could listen with something like `$('#yourInput').bind('keyup', function() { /* steps 2-4 */ })`